# How to create automatically some matrices for symbolic manipulation?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I want to create in an automatic way some matrices to do symbolic calculations with them. They look like these:

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 a & 0 & b & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 b & 0 & a & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
$$

So they have entry $a$ in at position $(1,1)$ and $(3,3)$ and entry $b$ at position $(1,3)$ and $(3,1)$ and the rest of the entries are 1 on the diagonal and zero elsewhere. So in general i want a symmetric $n\times n$ matrix with $b$ at position $(i,j)$ and $(j,i)$ and $a$ at position $(i,i)$ and $(j,j)$ How can i create these kind of matrices automatically?

Probably it is possible to write some function T[n,i,j] that gives as value the corresponding matrix.

(I have no insight into possible implementations of the solution, so additional Tags are welcome!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This makes a matrix of arbitrary size n :

```
f[n_, i_, j_] := 
 ReplacePart[  
          Array[0 &, {n, n}],       
          {{i, i} -> a, {j, j} -> a, {i, j} -> b, {j, i} -> b, {k_, k_} -> 1 }]     
f[4, 1, 3] //Grid
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for understanding what the OP wanted.  However, I still recommend a SparseArray approach.  See my updated answer for examples.

Comment: I have replaced `T[...]` by `f[...]` because symbols that begin with a uppercase are normally Mathematica built-in symbols

Answer (score 4):

You should take a look at [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SparseArray.html) and [`Band`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Band.html):

```
SparseArray[{
  Band[{1, 1}, {4, 4}] -> {a, 1},
  {1, 3} -> b, {3, 1} -> b
}] // MatrixForm
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 a & 0 & b & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 b & 0 & a & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right)$

---

It seems I misunderstood the output you wanted.  Here is a function that mimics andre's output, but uses the more efficient SparseArray format:

```
f1[n_, i_, j_] :=
 SparseArray[
  {{i, i} -> a, {j, j} -> a, {i, j} -> b, {j, i} -> b, {k_, k_} -> 1},
  {n, n}
 ]
```

For greater efficiency we can build a sparse `IdentityMatrix` and make replacements as andre did:

```
f2[n_, i_, j_] :=
 ReplacePart[
  IdentityMatrix[n, SparseArray],
  {{i, i} -> a, {j, j} -> a, {i, j} -> b, {j, i} -> b}
 ]
```

Syntax is the same:

```
f2[7, 5, 2] // MatrixForm
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & a & 0 & 0 & b & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & b & 0 & 0 & a & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right)$

Comment: To make this general for arbitrary size and position i tried `T[n_, i_, j_] := SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}, {n, n}] -> 1, {i, i} | {j, j} -> a, {i, j} | {j, i} -> b}]`which does not seem to work. I think this is now a question on properly defining a function.

Comment: @user11712 Okay, give me a minute to update my answer.

Comment: @user11712 I see for your Acceptance of andre's answer that I apparently misunderstood what you wanted.  Nevertheless I encourage you to use the SparseArray format instead for a matrix with a background value (default zero) as it is more efficient.  I shall add a function to my answer that mimics andre's output.